# SNMP MIB errors, cannot find module, etc

Tags: networking, centos, snmp, net-snmp, mib

This is my first stackoverflow question so I must apologize in advance for any mistakes.

I have for quite some time been experimenting with SNMP. I'm running a host using Centos 7, using net-snmp, and I've had agents on numerous network devices such as Juniper SRX100, E2200, Arista switches, HP proliant servers etc. I've had one issue that always persisted. 
No matter the device, certain MIBs seems to have issues working with other MIBs from the same manufacturer. For example:

```
[root@localhost mibs]# snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.20.102.12
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs
Cannot find module (CPQSINFO-MIB): At line 49 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/CPQNIC-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (CPQSTDEQ-MIB): At line 50 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/CPQNIC-MIB.txt
Did not find 'cpqSiServerSystemId' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/CPQNIC-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'cpqSePciSlotBoardName' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/CPQNIC-MIB.txt)
Cannot find module (CPQSINFO-MIB): At line 43 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/CPQHLTH-MIB.mib.txt
Did not find 'cpqSiServerSystemId' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/CPQHLTH-MIB.mib.txt)
Did not find 'cpqSiMemModuleSize' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/CPQHLTH-MIB.mib.txt)
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Integrated Lights-Out 4 2.03 Nov 07 2014
```

And the mibs in this folder(usr/share/snmp/mibs/) are

```
[root@localhost mibs]# ls
AGENTX-MIB.txt           HCNUM-TC.txt                         IPV6-TC.txt                RFC1155-SMI.txt              SNMPv2-CONF.txt
BRIDGE-MIB.txt           HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.txt               IPV6-TCP-MIB.txt           RFC1213-MIB.txt              SNMPv2-MIB.txt
CPQFCA-MIB.mib.txt       HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES.txt             IPV6-UDP-MIB.txt           RMON-MIB.txt                 SNMPv2-SMI.txt
CPQHLTH-MIB.mib.txt      IANA-ADDRESS-FAMILY-NUMBERS-MIB.txt  LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt         SCTP-MIB.txt                 SNMPv2-TC.txt
CPQHOST-MIB.mib.txt      IANA-LANGUAGE-MIB.txt                MTA-MIB.txt                SMUX-MIB.txt                 SNMPv2-TM.txt
CPQIDA-MIB.mib.txt       IANA-RTPROTO-MIB.txt                 NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB.txt     SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB.txt       TCP-MIB.txt
CPQNIC-MIB.txt           IANAifType-MIB.txt                   NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt  SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB.txt       TRANSPORT-ADDRESS-MIB.txt
CPQSINFO-MIB             IF-INVERTED-STACK-MIB.txt            NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt    SNMP-MPD-MIB.txt             TUNNEL-MIB.txt
CPQSINFO-MIB.txt         IF-MIB.txt                           NET-SNMP-MIB.txt           SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB.txt    UCD-DEMO-MIB.txt
CPQSTDEQ-MIB.txt         INET-ADDRESS-MIB.txt                 NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB.txt      SNMP-PROXY-MIB.txt           UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt
CPQSTSYS-MIB.txt         IP-FORWARD-MIB.txt                   NET-SNMP-TC.txt            SNMP-TARGET-MIB.txt          UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB.txt     IP-MIB.txt                           NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB.txt      SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB.txt   UCD-IPFWACC-MIB.txt
DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB.txt  IPV6-FLOW-LABEL-MIB.txt              NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB.txt   SNMP-USM-AES-MIB.txt         UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
DISMAN-SCRIPT-MIB.txt    IPV6-ICMP-MIB.txt                    NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB.txt   SNMP-USM-DH-OBJECTS-MIB.txt  UDP-MIB.txt
EtherLike-MIB.txt        IPV6-MIB.txt                         RFC-1215.txt               SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB.txt
```

And the the inside of the first error message

```
CPQNIC-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    compaq                  FROM CPQHOST-MIB
    Counter                 FROM RFC1155-SMI
    Gauge                   FROM RFC1155-SMI
    TimeTicks               FROM RFC1155-SMI
    DisplayString           FROM RFC1213-MIB
    OBJECT-TYPE             FROM RFC-1212
    TRAP-TYPE               FROM RFC-1215
    sysName                 FROM RFC1213-MIB
    ipAdEntAddr             FROM RFC1213-MIB
    cpqHoTrapFlags          FROM CPQHOST-MIB
    cpqSiServerSystemId     FROM CPQSINFO-MIB
    cpqSePciSlotBoardName   FROM CPQSTDEQ-MIB;
```

With the last two lines being 49 and 50.
I've been getting these errors with various MIB files from different manufacturers. But I cannot imagine that the manufacturers would supply broken MIBs, when they're specifically designed for the device I'm using them for.

I simply cannot figure out what's wrong. The snmp.conf file points towards all files in the mibs folder. I've tried renaming them, altering file extensions etc.

Comment: You put your trust to the wrong place. A vendor can provide you broken MIB documents as they don't know what tool you will use to compile them and usually it is hard to ship all dependencies. In your case, try another MIB compiler to see what dependency is missing and then get back to NET-SNMP if you cannot understand its messages.

Comment: I was under the impression that a MIB compiler was used when you write your own MIBs, not when you want to use them for your snmp polls. Even so I started fiddling around with a MIB compiler and found something completely different. When I save the MIB files from the vendor they save by default as a text document. When I changed file type to "all" and added the .mib extension to the files I stopped having these problems. The question that persists now is why vendor-supplied mibs points towards OIDs that have no value.

Comment: Such as: [root@localhost mibs]# snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.20.102.12 cpqSsPowerSupplyChassisIndex
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs
CPQSTSYS-MIB::cpqSsPowerSupplyChassisIndex = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID

Why would a MIB for this specific device point towards an OID that isn't being used?

Comment: "MIB compiler" is really generic term for anything that reads MIB module files, optionally performs some validation, and converts to another format. It could be source code, it could be XML, it could be PDF, it could be anything. Some SNMP tools like MIB browsers and such don't read MIB module syntax directly but use an intermediate format from such a compiler. Some do.

Comment: As to CPQSTSYS-MIB::cpqSsPowerSupplyChassisIndex or other objects that appear to not be used, it could be that MIB is not specific to a single product, but to multiple products or a product line, some that support those objects and some that don't. Also, "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID" is a totally different error from "Cannot find module". The former is coming from the agent; the latter is coming from your CLI tools.